# Email template variables in shopware 6

Tags: shopware, shopware6

How can I dump variables available for my e-mail templates in shopware 6, and where can I find them if I cannot dump them.
Thank you

Comment: Please share some code of what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to dump those variables in twig. You can have a look at the entity definitions, e.g. the order: https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/c5b78af033b1438e497e28ec7b10ab25cedb8a0d/src/Core/Checkout/Order/OrderDefinition.php

And then you can check the linked entities and so on.

You could propably dump the variables in the send function of the mailservice: https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/cb9229240c111c70594bbe7e1a8b4f018162dc44/src/Core/Content/MailTemplate/Service/MailService.php#L109

Answer (score 1):

I know its late, but if someone else stumbles upon this, you can use `MailBeforeValidateEvent` as follows:

```php
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            MailBeforeValidateEvent::class => 'mailValidate'
        ];
    }

    public function mailValidate(MailBeforeValidateEvent $event): void
    {
        // Here you get the template data
        $templateData = $event->getTemplateData();

        // Here you get the data
        $data = $event->getData();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the MailService and dump it from there. All data will appear under Debug in your Symfony Console (in case you're using the development env from Git)